# How do I extract who signed a controlled access section in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, signed, lotus

I would like to export the contents of a Lotus Notes database to XML.  In the resulting file I would like to see who had signed a particular controlled access section.  I know that the digital signatures are not exported.  All I need to know is who signed the section and when did he/she do it.

In what way can I use the DXL Exporter to export the name and date of who signed the section?  What do I look for?

Answer (score 0):

If a Notes document is signed, the DXL exporter puts the name of the signer in the <[wassignedby](http://www.ipi.org/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/97e8f542f17e6bd38525731b00491380?OpenDocument)> tag and puts `sign="true"` on all <[item](http://www.ipi.org/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/23d339c41d0579d38525731b0049083d?OpenDocument)> tags that are signed.

I haven't found a way to find the date of the signature. It might be possible to look it up using the UNID of the document and checking `LastModified` property of the `$Signature` note item.

Comment: The wassignedby tag is assigned to a document and is used by the Designer when someone signs their database, doesn't it?  Even if it did apply to the document, that does me no good because I need to have the name of the person who signed a section of the document.

Comment: I don't think you can sign an individual section of a document, it only has one signature. You can however choose which items should be covered by that signature. Do you have access to the code that signs the section?